# Android - whether installing Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors successfully or not

Tags: android

My Computer processor is AMD.Then I did as here:https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for.html
but when I open Windows Features, I can't find Hyper-V,Windows Sandbox,and Windows Hypervisor Platform.It seems like they don't exist there.Then I just skipped this step.
Finally,this is the result:

[image]

Does this mean I installed it successfully?if doesn't, what should I do?

Comment: Far I know that is only available on Windows 10 Pro (not the “Home” version). it works on AMD and Intel.

Comment: besides,"成功"means successfully in English.